# Difference between console.log and sys.puts in node.js?

Tags: javascript, console, node.js

In node.js you can use `console.log` or `sys.puts` to print out to the screen.

What is the preferred method and what is the difference between these?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

`sys.puts` simply prints the given string in the logs.

But if you want to print a more complex object (Array, JSON, JSObject) you have to use `console.log` because you want to "look inside" of the object.

`sys.puts` would give you only "[object object]" for example.

Comment: yes, however you don't HAVE to use console logs to see the object.   sys.puts("check out this funky object in detail: " + sys.inspect(yourobject));

Answer (score 16):

Both just write to the stdout stream.  The difference is that `sys.puts` just `toString`'s the first argument, and `console.log` takes multiple arguments, and will `sys.inspect` the first arg if it's not a string.

Comment: `sys.inspect` is now `util.inspect`

Comment: Actually console is used to print to stdout and stderr streams.

Answer (score 9):

Puts is deprecated in since version 0.2.3

Comment: Please cite the source by linking to where you found the information.

Comment: Speaking of deprecation, it looks like the 'sys' module has become the 'util' module. The puts() method is still around, but the utils.p() prints a deprecated warning.

Comment: @xer0x : 'sys' module was renamed to be 'util'. It was a Fix on require('sys') #3577

Answer (score 3):

Also you can use console.log without requiring the sys module.

Answer (score 2):

```
console.dir(objectToInspect)
```

This might be another way to inspect objects.

Answer (score 1):

```
sys.puts([...]);
```

Is a synchronous output function. Simply it is a blocking function as in Node.js language.

```
console.log([data], [...]);
```

Prints to stdout with newline.

For more Info:

http://nodejs.org/api/stdio.html#stdio_console_log_data

http://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_puts

**Note: 'sys' module was renamed to be 'util' (Supported by [link](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/lib/sys.js)) It was a Fix #3577**

Answer (score 0):

The preferred method is `console.log()`. `sys.puts()` has been removed.

---

The `sys` module was renamed `util` with this [commit](https://github.com/nodejs/node-v0.x-archive/commit/e38eb0c5a4d4e8497f5815be81994ddb01fbceb7#diff-23937c0fc3badcf29d5d29c4721906d3a79b981359a7b3f383a21c9d3a5d7478) dated Oct 12, 2010. So `sys.puts()` became `util.puts()`. `util.puts()` was added in v0.3.0, deprecation since v0.11.3, and removed in v12.0.0. The [documentation](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v15.x/api/all.html#DEP0027) advises to use `console.log()` instead.