# Is there any analogue of "console" in server-side javascript V8?

Tags: javascript, v8

To dump some debugging information in client-side javascript I can use `console.log(myVar)`. Can I do the same thing in server-side javascript which runs on V8? Is there any way to dump data to error_log file or something?

Comment: by server side v8 - do you mean node.js? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3904273/difference-between-console-log-and-sys-puts-in-node-js

Comment: if you call `console.log(x)` in node.js, `x` will show up in the terminal that you're running node.js in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

```
$ node -e "console.log('hello world')";
```